# Como hago esto con javascript creando calculadora personal

Tags: javascript

estoy creando una calculadora que lo que hace es que yo meto el producto y la cantidad y me hace el calculo, pero no se que pasa que no me aparece el resultado, si me pueden ayudar.

Función para crear lista de compra y calcular

```
let natilla = 'Natilla'
natilla = 0.69
function CrearLista() {
        let alerta = prompt('Introduce el producto');
        let cantidad = prompt('Introduce la cantidad del producto');
        if( alerta == null || alerta == '' ) {
            
            alert('Debes introducir un valor');
        } 
        if( cantidad == null || cantidad == '' ) {
            
            alert('Debes introducir un valor');
        } 

        if (alerta == natilla) {
            let calculo = alerta * cantidad;
            console.log  = (` El precio final es: ${parseFloat(calculo)}`);
        }
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, la consola se queda en blanco no aparece el calculo.

Comment: no me queda claro porque sobrescribir la variable natilla, ya que al momento de la validación con la variable alerta nunca sera true.

Comment: Al sobreescribir la variable Natilla le estoy diciendo que vale ese precio, y alert es para que le avise de que tiene que introducir un valor en el prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en la lógica de como realizar el proceso.

el primer error que noto es igualar la función console.log.

```
console.log  = (` El precio final es: ${parseFloat(calculo)}`);
```

Después es crear la variable natilla y darle el valor "Natilla" y después sobrescribirla.

```
let natilla = 'Natilla'
natilla = 0.69
```

Esto ocasiona que al validar con lo que se introduce en el navegador nunca llegue al calculo

```
   if (alerta == natilla) {
     let calculo = alerta * cantidad;
     console.log  = (` El precio final es: ${parseFloat(calculo)}`);
   }
```

Ya con los errores corregidos el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
let natilla = 'Natilla';
let valor_natilla = 0.69;
CrearLista();
function CrearLista() {
  let alerta = prompt('Introduce el nombre del producto');
  let cantidad = prompt('Introduce la cantidad del producto');
  if( alerta == null || alerta == '' ) {
      alert('Debes introducir un valor');
  }
  if( cantidad == null || cantidad == '' ) {
      alert('Debes introducir un valor');
  }
  
  if (alerta == natilla) {
      let calculo = valor_natilla * cantidad;
      console.log(` El precio final es: ${calculo}`);
  }else{
    console.log('no existe el producto');
  }
}
```

Creo que asi lo tenias planeado la funcionalidad, espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let natilla = 'Natilla'
natilla = 0.69
CrearLista();
function CrearLista() {
        let alerta = prompt('Introduce el producto');
        let cantidad = prompt('Introduce la cantidad del producto');
        if( alerta == null || alerta == '' ) {
            
            alert('Debes introducir un valor');
        } 
        if( cantidad == null || cantidad == '' ) {
            
            alert('Debes introducir un valor');
        } 

        
            var calculo = alerta * cantidad;
            alert("Resultado: " + calculo  );
        
    }
```

Ok, Entendí lo que querías decir a mi me salió el así pruébalo

Comment: ¿Cual era el error del OP? ¿Qué estaba haciendo mal? ¿Cómo se debe hacer correctamente? Nada de eso está explicado aquí; es sólo un trozo de código sin explicación.

Comment: el unico cambio que hiciste fue colocar un Alert para mostrar el resultado.